# FusionCharts with React and ref

Tags: reactjs, ref, fusioncharts

I am trying to use FusionCharts but am reusing some code from a different charting library and am trying to see how I can do the same with FusionCharts.

IN the return statement of the React component there is:

```
ref={node => this.element = node}
```

How do I reference this in the Component itself?

IN the create portion of the code it reads:

```
element: this.element
```

How do I do similar in FusionCHarts?

Comment: Please show some code and highlight you problem by telling what you tried and what is the issue. Otherwise, you might not get any answers or would be down voted by some or even the question might get closed. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the chart reference in the hook ? You may want to check https://github.com/fusioncharts/react-fusioncharts-component